# Static file Go web app always returns 404

Tags: go

I have a very basic Go web app which is simply supposed to serve static files from a public sub-folder:

```
package main

import (
"net/http"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
    mux.Handle("/", fs)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8181", mux)
}
```

If I run the app (go run main.go) it starts, but when I visit

```
localhost:8181/readme.txt
```

or

```
localhost:8181/index.html
```

both of which exist within the public sub folder, I get a 404 error returned. Nothing is logged (that I know of), but I’m at odds to understand why it is not being served.

Any suggestions welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Print the working directory of your app when it starts. You need to make sure that the relative path to `public` is `./public` (even better, don't rely on a relative path)

Comment: you running server on 8181 port, but visting 8081?

Comment: Since your URL path isn't the same as the local path, you need to use StripPrefix. See the example in the godocs: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer_stripPrefix

Comment: @wiredeye: Apologies, that was me just playing about changing port numbers *in case* there was a problem with a given port.Fixed in post now and I'm definitely hitting the same port as I'm listening on (else I wouldn't get a 404 being returned)

Comment: @JimB: I tried logging os.Getwd() but that doesn't return anything. Can you provide an example please so I can understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @driusan: Didn't seem to help:
mux.Handle("/", http.StripPrefix("/public", fs))

Comment: @LDJ: `os.Getwd` must return *something*. The process has a working directory, or you're getting some sort of OS error. Regardless, giving the pull path to `public` will show whether that's the issue or not.